# Android: Binding to remote service only succeeds when debugging the service

Tags: android, debugging, service, connection

I have written an library connecting to a remote service that calls

```
    return context.bindService(bindIntent,
            serviceConnectionSmartCard, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

with context being the ApplicationContext and serviceConnectionSmartCard being my custom ServiceConnection

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (waitForConnection) {
            waitForConnection = false;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    if(service == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Binding to Service failed.");
        smartCardReaderService.onConnected(null);
    } else {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Attached to Server.");
        IConnectionService connectionService = IConnectionService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        smartCardReaderService.onConnected(connectionService);
    }
}
```

And on Service side I have the following in onBind():

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "onBind");
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    return iConnectionService.asBinder();
}
```

with iConnectionService being an implementation of my AIDL file.

Now my problem: It works as long as I debug the Service (set Breakpoint on the return Statement)
however it doesn't work when I debug the Activity instead. The ServiceConnection never returns.

BTW: I call

```
startActivityForResult(...);
```

calling a remote Activity in Activity.onCreate. Could this be an issue here?
I simply don't know how to debug such strange behaviour...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind. android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger(); was the problem. I didn't really think it would break my program. :/ Commented it out and now everything works like a charm.

Comment: Mention your detailed solution in an answer and accept your own answer, it can help others in future.

Comment: I can't as I am new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. Just uncommented

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

as it will silently wait for the debugger to attach even if not started by my debug application - which is never going to happen.